# Set the LSB of Java java.awt.Color RGB components

Tags: java, colors, rgb, pixel

Is there a method for changing the LSB value of java.awt.Color RGB components?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Change one particular color component?

Comment: Yes, how is this different from calling `setBlue()` on a `Color` object (assuming RGB space)?

Comment: Maybe not specifically Color class. What I'd reall like to know is how to set the Least Significant bit of an integer to either 1 or 0 at will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning a bit on:

```
int value = someValue | 0x1;
```

Turning a bit off:

```
int value = someValue & (~0x1);
```

Toggling the bit on or off if it was off or on before:

```
int value = someValue ^ 0x1;
```

In other words:
someValue is binary OR'ed with a number with the LSB on so the resulting number will have its LSB on too.

someValue is AND'ed with a number with all bits *except* LSB on so the resulting number will have LSB OFF.

someValue is XOR'ed with with a number with the LSB on, so the resulting number will have its LSB toggled.

Answer (score 3):

The Color class is immutable, you can't change anything. However, you can create a new color with whatever value you want. For example,

```
   int oldValue = oldColor.getRGB();
   int newValue = (oldValue & 0xFFFFFF00) | (lsb & 0xFF);
   Color newColor = new Color(newValue);
```